# Add an icon to the package and access it

Tags: android

There are several java files combined into a package. Is it possible to add an icon to this package and access it from this package?

assumption:

```
package com.foobar;
import com.foobar.Resources;
...
.setSmallIcon(Resources.drawable.icon)
```

I know how to put images in the main application package. These images are accessed through the R package, which must be imported using the name of the main package. `import main.package.name.R`. But I need to avoid using the main package name and have the ability to access the image.

Comment: can you explain more about your problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use something like this to access it.

```
.setSmallIcon(getResources().getDrawable(com.foobar.drawable.icon));
```

Your other "package" must be an android library module, just include the drawables in the usual res/drawable folder.

Ensure you include your other module within your main module by adding it to your gradle.

```
implementation project(':foobar')
```

Also ensure you include both your main and foobar module in your settings.gradle

```
include ':main', ':foobar'
```

Comment: Thanks. Please, how to put the icon in com.foobar package?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include this